# Export motion path

Tags: animation, export

I am working on motion planning for automatic vehicles and like to use blender for two things:

1. Define scenes with obstacles, both static and moving, and export them to do calculations with
2. Feed some objects with pre-calculated trajectories (that is, "motion path")

The question is: what's the best way to do both things?

A big benefit for me would be that I had a very good scenario editor and a good animation program to display my results.

Comment: Pick a simple file format that blender can both export and import and work with that. The file format should support animations. If you'd like to see it in blender real-time you can write your own interchange format and with using the blender api script a client-server system to pipe the data from blender and display it in blender.

Comment: I see a great question but no good answer here. Answers for writing a custom solution don't make sense when Blender is such a capable environment. Who has done this, both in real time or for post-processing?? It's a timely, valuable topic. What's the workflow. What are coordinate frame options? What file formats make sense???

Comment: This tutorial explains multi-vehicle scenario setup and animation in Blender. It's a few years old but the concepts and workflow are still relevant:
https://www.blendernation.com/2007/01/02/car-animation-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need realtime communication of blender and another program, Alembic would be your exchange format to go with, as it supports animated mesh data of any kind. As far as I know, it does however not store whether an object is static or not but I am sure this could be circumvented (using materials etc.). If you do however need realtime communication, writing a server/client application would be what you need, as Jaroslav suggested.